# I wanna ask that why the regex ^(19([6-9]\d|5[2-9]))|(20([01]\d|2[0-7]))$ will reject 2027XXXX but not 1952XXXX

Tags: google-forms

I have also tried to add {4} at the end of the

```
regex(^(19([6-9]\d|5[2-9]))|(20([01]\d|2[0-7])){4}$)
```

However, it doesn't help to reject a longer input like `19991`
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86GO8.png)

Comment: Remove the `{4}` from the end of your pattern and it works as expected, [see the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/l9xFOx/1).

Comment: I know, but what I need is to limit the length of the input.